# Who were the red-robed citizens of Jedha City?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, rogue-one

In Rogue One, on the streets of Jedha City, we saw several tall figures wearing almost Imperial-Guard-like robes. Some of them also wore masks and others seemed to have some kind of a helmet under their hoods. They all carried unique staffs.

[image]

Who were they? Were they related to the Church of the Force somehow? Maybe the novelization or the Visual Guide gives some information.

Additionally, is it possible that at least some of them became the Knights of Ren? One of them is holding a similar kind of a staff.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Rogue One: Ultimate Visual Guide](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Rogue-Ultimate-Visual-x/dp/146545263X) names them as

[**Killi Gimm**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/StarWarsJedha), a human Disciple of the Whills

[image]

**Silvani Phest**, an Anomid Disciple of the Whills

[image]

**Toshdor Ni**, A Lorrdian Devotee of the Brotherhood of Beatific Countenance and his (unnamed) colleague.

[image]

Along with **Angber Trel**, **The High Priest** and **Omisha Joyo**.

[image]

Comment: How do you take pictures with a fridge?

Comment: You might want to slow down with edits for a bit ;)

Comment: @Gallifreyan - This one was to improve image quality

Answer (score 21):

### Pilgrims

The novelization seems to imply that they are pilgrims.

> Jedha City is gone. Jyn examined the thought numbly. The death of
> Jedha City meant the death of Saw; the deaths of many or all of his
> soldiers; the deaths of **red-robed pilgrims** and blustering water
> vendors.
>
> <sub>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*</sub>

The [officially licensed](http://www.starwars.com/games-apps/star-wars-card-trader) [trading cards](http://www.starwars.com/games-apps/star-wars-card-trader) concur, which makes it clear that the novelization is talking about *these* red-robed pilgrims and not some other ones:

[image]

Comment: Dang, your answers came so close together and they contain the same information... Which one was first?

Comment: @DBPriGuy - Mine has something extra.

Comment: Ah! Didn't see your edit til now. My apologies :)

Comment: @DBPriGuy - If you hover over the "***answered x hours ago***" it brings up a tooltip showing the time the answer was posted.

Comment: @DBPriGuy - You can also see who posted first in the question's timeline; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/148287/timeline

Comment: @DBPriGuy - You may wish to note that while two answers came almost immediately, the [best one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/148302/20774) came slightly later :-)

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 11):

The novelization describes them as pilgrims to Jedha (emphasis mine):

> The death of Jedha City meant the death of Saw; the deaths of many or all of his soldiers; the deaths of **red-robed pilgrims** and blustering water vendors. It meant the death of the girl she'd swept into her arms during the fighting in the plaza—the brutal, pointless death of the only person she'd helped in any way since this mission began...
>
> <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelization* Chapter 9</sup>

But that's about all we know; earlier in the novel, Jyn remarks that pilgrims from many faiths come to Jedha, so all we can say is that they worship the Force *somehow*:

> [S]he didn't know enough about the local religions to speculate; pilgrims from a hundred faiths came to the moon from across the galaxy, and all of them blurred together into the same pathetic cult, chanting and moaning and squirming under the Empire's boot.
>
> <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelization* Chapter 4</sup>

It's certainly possible that some of them became Knights of Ren, but we have no evidence one way or another.